# How to define a global variable in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, abort

I have a small problem with the declaration of the variable in JavaScript. At the beginning of the file i declare a variable via `var send;`, after it i have `$(document).ready(function()` in wich i have recursive loop with `setTimeOut` in which i assign to a variable Ajax request and after it in the end of file i have an `abort()`. So it likes like:

```
var send;
$(document).ready(function(){
//somecode
    function loop(){
        send = $.getScript('index.php', function(data){
            //somecode
        }
    }
//somecode
}
function one_more(){
    send.abort();
}
```

The problem is that on `send.abort();` i receive:

> TypeError: send is undefined
>
> send.abort();

Where i am wrong?

Comment: When do you call `one_more()`?

Comment: Your question is very poorly written and so is the code sample. Please read it over and make some revisions.

Comment: @CoryDanielson what you can not understand?

Comment: In your code sample one_more() is never called and loop() is never called. You mentioned a recursive loop, but I don't see any loop

Answer (score 1):

As `send` is only defined in the `loop()` function, it will only be defined once that is called (and called only within the scope of the document ready handler)

I assume you're calling `one_more()` before `send` is defined.

For the purposes of illustration, what you have above is essentially

```
var send;
send.abort();
```

A quick work-around would be to define `send` with the appropriately named methods, eg

```
var send = send || {abort: function(){}};
```

This would stop the errors but you really should work out when things are executed and defined

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, is this piece of code wrong:

```
function loop(){
    send = $.getScript('index.php', function(data){
        //somecode
    }
}
```

It should be this:

```
function loop(){
    send = $.getScript('index.php', function(data){
        //somecode
    });
}
```

see the ); at the end of send = ....

Comment: Good catch but I'm guessing the OP just made a typo

Comment: @Phil, i also geus it, but you never know sure....

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of the `send` variable happens inside the ready function.
When you reach the `send.abort()` instruction, the `ready` function has not been executed yet.

Answer (score -1):

Defining `window.varname` will make the variable global. I think `window` is like the root of all variables because you can call `window.window.window.window.window.window.window.window` and it will return `window`.

Comment: A variable declaration at top-level is the same as `window.varname`.